# Arrow function not being recognized react

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions, parsing-error

```js
import React, {
  useState
} from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import './testmodal.css';


class Testmodal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false)
    return ( <
      div className = "Testmodal" >
      <
      div >
      <
      button onClick {
        () => setModalIsOpen(true)
      } > Edit Profile < /button> <
      /div> <
      Modal isOpen = {
        modalIsOpen
      } >
      <
      h2 > Modal Type < /h2> <
      p > Modal body < /p> <
      div >
      <
      button onClick = {
        () => setModalIsOpen(false)
      } > < /button> <
      /div> <
      /Modal> <
      /div>
    )
  }
}

export default Testmodal;
```

I'm trying to make a modal component that can be exported onto a website I'm creating but for some reason when I run the file on my local machine it's picking up an error at the arrow function.

[Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..." with a red arrow pointing at my arrow function brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8e0q.png)

Comment: looks like you are missing an `=` between `onClick` and `{`

Comment: Now the error is showing an invalid hook call

Comment: Hooks are not valid inside of a Class Component. Hooks are only useable in other Hooks and Function Components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Your issue is in using [React Class Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) with `hooks`.

`Hooks` are designed to be used with [functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) (Take a look at the first example).

Class Components incorporate usage of `this.state`, while functional components incorporate usage of `useState, useX, useY` (hooks) as you did.

Take a look at this fixed code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import './testmodal.css';

const Testmodal = () => {
  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="Testmodal">
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(true)}> Edit Profile </button>
      </div>
      <Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen}>
        <h2> Modal Type </h2> <p> Modal body </p>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(false)}> </button>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Testmodal;
```

What I changed is migrate the component from `Class Testmodal extends React.Component` to `const Testmodal = () => {...}`

That is called migrating from Class Component to Functional component.

Once the component is functional, you can use hooks inside of it, but remember to only use it in the [highest scope](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).

Comment: Beat me to it, here is a runnable example: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rmnd4f?file=index.tsx](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rmnd4f?file=index.tsx)

Comment: @UsamaAhmed If it is the correct answer, could you mark it as so? :)